# Migrating Struts from 1 to 2: action failing with "page not found" exception

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts

I am migrating the Struts from 1.1 to 2.3.35 version, I have written struts.xml looks like below:

==============================

```
    <!-- <package name="default" extends="struts-default"> -->

            <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
             <package name="struts-migration" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

<global-results>
 <result name="welcome" type="redirect">/pages/Login</result>
 <result name="failure" type="redirect">add_new_test_exercise_status.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
                    <action  name="/pages/Login" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action">

                            <param name="className">struts.actions.LoginAction</param>
            <result name="success">/struts/login.jsp</result>
            </action>

    </package>
```

==============================

When i am trying the access the page using the RUL, getting page not found exception.
http://localhost:8080/Struts/pages/Login

Could anyone please share any document or steps to migrate from struts 1.1 to 2.3.35 version .

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:8080/Struts/welcome`?

Comment: FYI, Struts 2.3 is EOL in six months, so might want to re-think which version you're migrating to.

Comment: I can't read the XML because of its random indentation, but why are you going to `/Struts/...` instead of `/pages/Login`?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev There are no actions with the word `welcome` anywhere AFAICT.